# Sendmany bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, sending

I am trying to use the `sendmany` parameter of `bitcoin-cli`. My problem is as follows: is there any way that I could tell `sendmany`, to calculate the input accounts based on the balances, instead of using a specified account as the first parameter?

I've read, that the `accounts` parameter is deprecated, and shouldn't be used anymore, if this is the case, what is the proper usage of the `sendmany` function?

Others have written, that in this case, the first parameter should be simply ommited by adding a `""` the empty string to it, but I somehow managed to create an address which has as it's account name, the empty string `""`. Whenever I try to use `sendmany` with the empty string it always says that I have insufficient funds (which is true, if we look at the address with the empty string as account name, but it would be false, looking at all the other addresses that I have).

I've tried to find a way, to delete the address which has the empty string as it's account name, but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Anyone facing/faced a simmilar situation that knows a solution to this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you should probably file a bug report that it's possible to get into this situation in the first place.  The only way I can think of to recover is to dump all your private keys and import them into a new wallet (without using accounts this time).

Comment: Basically, it looks like, that when I create my wallet, `Bitcoin Core` automatically creates an empty account for me, with an address.

Answer (score 1):

Tthe empty string `""` is for the default account, not for all accounts in your wallet. Whenever you add a label to an address, what you are really doing is adding it to an account. If you want to be able to spend from all of your addresses, you will need to move all of your addresses into the same account, i.e. remove their labels and make them the same label.

Comment: There is also a "move" command that simply increments the balance of one account and decrements another. You can use this to move all balance to one account.